# retornar al activity principal en navigation draw

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-intent

Buenas. Cuando levanto mi aplicación, la primera pantalla que me muestra es el contenedor principal de los fragments que tengo en el navigation draw. Al seleccionar los items que me llevan a los distintos fragments no he podido encontrar manera de regresar a la primera pantalla. Estoy seguro que un intent es absurdo, pero no tengo idea de cómo regresar. Muchas Gracias por sus respuestas.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        // Handle the camera action
        ///volver a la pantalla principal
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_pedido) {
        // Handle the camera action
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new Pedido()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_stok) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new Stock()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_deuda) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new Deuda()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_despacho) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new Despacho()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ventas) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new Ventas()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ruta) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new Ruta()).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

xml principal

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_vendedor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_vendedor"
    app:menu="@menu/vendedor_drawer" />
```

xml app bar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_vendedor" />
```

xml nav header

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

xml drawer

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:title="Menu"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</group>
<item android:title="Transacciones"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pedido"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Ingrese Pedido"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </menu>
</item>

<item android:title="Consultas"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_stok"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Stock" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_deuda"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Deuda" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_despacho"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Despacho" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ventas"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Avance de Ventas"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ruta"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Hoja de Ruta" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Que pasa cuando se preciona atras en el dispositivo?

Comment: @Einer  no quiero retroceder. He creado un menu lateral en el que se tiene un item "menu" que me debe servir como enlace directo a la pantalla principal que me sale cuando cargo la aplicación.

Comment: Publica el xml a ver.

Comment: @Einer he puesto todos los xml

Comment: @ICRUZ la pantalla principal no tiene un fragmento es así?

Comment: @Jorgesys es correcto. solo uso la pantalla principal como contenedor de los otros fragments.

Comment: ok entonces usa para regresa  popBackStackImmediate()  y puedes usar getBackStackEntryCount() para validar si existen Fragmentos cargados, revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: No esta muy claro lo que preguntas, debes ser más especifico ya que no indicas como quieres regresar.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el fragment con el que inicia la aplicación?
Veo que en el nav_menu, que supongo es el fragment inicial, no has agregado ni un fragment

Answer (score 0):

Al revisar tu código veo que cargas Fragmentos en tu Activity principal, pero la principal no carga ningún `Fragment` al inicio, puedes usar este método usando `onBackPressed()`, que regresa al `Fragment` anterior usando [**popBackStackImmediate()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate()) , si es que se encuentra, al llegar al MainActivity puedes implementar que salga de la Activity mediante `finish()`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

       Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.contenedor);

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {               
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }/*else{
            finish();  //Sale de Activity principal.
        }*/


}
```

Comment: No quiero regresar de uno en uno hasta el inicio. Deseo regresar al activity principal presionando el item "menu", que se encuentra en el navigation draw, desde cualquier pantalla en la que me encuentre. el código no funcionó.

Comment: ¿No funciono porque regresa de "uno en uno hasta el inicio"?

Comment: no, no hace nada cuando presiono el item "menu"

Comment: Lo que deseas es entonces agregar un item en el menu para regresar a home? No esta muy claro lo que preguntas, el código este código no indica que si lo agregas va a realizar eso, debes ser más especifico en tus preguntas por ejemplo comentar de que forma quieres regresar a mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Para regresar al menu principal.

```
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        // Handle the camera action
       ///volver a la pantalla principal
       NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this,  new Intent(this, MiContenedorPrincipal.class));
       return true;
```

Para realizar navegación hacia arriba prueba con agregar:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

.....

if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }


        }
```

Comment: se cierra la aplicacion al presionar el item

Comment: ¿cual es el error?

Answer (score 0):

En onCreate del MainActivity debes agregar (`add`) el fragment con el cual va 
iniciar la aplicación:

```
FragmentMenu fragment = new FragmentMenu();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.contenedor, fragment, "iniciofragment");
        ft.commit();
```

`FragmentMenu`o como se llame tu fragment inicial.

Y también debes agregar ese mismo fragment de inicio en onNavigationItem:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        ///volver a la pantalla principal
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, FragmentMenu()).commit();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_pedido) ...
```

Comment: El OP comenta que al iniciar la pantalla principal, no tiene ningún Fragment.

Comment: Aunque menciona "la primera pantalla que me muestra es el contenedor principal de los fragments". Tendría que aclararnos eso. O es una pantalla en blanco o que